# How to define base URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory, base-url

I am redirecting

```
https://www.example.com/inter.php?pid=<a number>&title=<the page title>
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/<a number>/<the-page-title>
```

Now I want to move the website to a sub folder so the redirection will be

```
https://www,example.com/folder/inter.php?pid=<a number>&title=<the page title>
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/folder/<a number>/<the-page-title>
```

I am using the below .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /inter\.php\?pid=([^&\s]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ inter.php?pid=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Please Suggest.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `.htaccess` in root directory you can add /foldername

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/inter\.php\?pid=([^&\s]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /foldername/%1/%2? [L,R]
```

To both rules

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ inter.php?pid=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Please try above rules it I didn't tried it for now.